# How to safely construct URL link in the Notifying message when you don't know your domain name?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Here is the problem, I am building a retail site using Gwt. My system has a private in-house message box system.

When customer successfully ordered an item, my system will send a notification (including a link to let user view orders in the order page, ex: "`abc.com#!order;orderID=61`") to the user's private in-house message box & to the user's email.

-When sending to "the user's private in-house message box" we don't need to know the domain in advanced co the user already staying my website so the link could mist the domain part like this "`#!order;orderID=61`".

My question is "How to safely construct the URL link in the Notifying message when you don't know your domain name?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a backslash '/' to create a relative link:

```
<a href="/?orderID=61">This is your order</a>
```

Comment: we create this line at server level "<a href="/?orderID=61">This is your order</a>", so is it safe?

Comment: however it's hard to sanitize "<a href="

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize it? You only need to sanitize something that a user types in. You create this link yourself, so it is safe.

Comment: but then user can be able to send message to each other, so they will put text into the TextArea & we have to process these user entering text when showing it in HTML format. How to deal with it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok, My Private Message Box system have a box that allows user to type the message & they will send that message to each other. So, the user can enter any malicious html they want & when showing the message in HTML format I have to make sure there is no malicious HtML code.

Comment: Or i could use "Rich Text Area" (RTA) but not sure if RTA does all the sanitation job

Comment: You do need to sanitize the user message, but how is this related to your question about constructing a link?

Comment: do we need to sanitize "Rich Text Area"?

Comment: Yes. There are different levels of cleaning - you may allow basic tags like <p> and <b>, but no other tags (like <script>).

Comment: Thax for ur info, i think i just go with blank text & just make url like a text line & user have to copy & paste. This cos user only 3 sec but it the safest way.